# Right embedding for NLP Classifier negative sentence

Tags: nlp, text-classification, embedding

I have a classifier which has classes - "approve" , "reject"  and many other classes.
I am using multiple language model based pre trained embedding from `sapcy`. So when I have a input sentence like `I approve this offer` , my classifier correctly predicts class `approve`.

However when I have input sentence such as
`I can not reject this offer` I want class to be `approve` but classifier is predicting `reject`.

One solution is to improve quality of my annotations which is time consuming. I want to solve by choosing right embedding I want to know if there is embedding which would show higher similarity between `not reject` and `approve` or is there any other solution.

Comment: are you using ner or text classification?

Comment: intent classification

Comment: are you okay to use huggingface transformers for intent classification ?

Comment: I am using RASA and DIET classifier.

Comment: try using huggingface roberta model